# regex textblock

Tags: regex, powershell

I want this a regex to be formatted over several lines for clarity. Like this:

```
$regexDatum = [regex] @"
^\<(?<TargetAddress>[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]),
(?<ReadStatus>\w\w),
(?<s1le>\d+),
(?<s1te>\d+),
(?<e1le>\d+),
(?<e1z>-{0,1}\d+),
(?<e1te>\d+),
(?<e2le>\d+),
(?<e2z>-{0,1}\d+),
(?<e2te>\d+),
(?<s2le>\d+),
(?<s2te>\d+),
"@
```

But I find that the whitespace at the end of the line cause problems and the backtick seems to compound the problem.  Hence I'm forced to put in all on one line - hello column 240 ...

Most C-compilers would allow me to something like this (slashes not corrected for C-compiler):

```
char[] regexDatum = "^\<(?<TargetAddress>[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]),"
    "(?<ReadStatus>\w\w),"
    "(?<s1le>\d+),"
    "(?<s1le>\d+),"
    "(?<s1te>\d+),"
    "(?\<e1le>\d+),"
    "(?<e1z>-{0,1}\d+),"
    "(?<e1te>\d+),"
    "(?<e2le>\d+),"
    "(?<e2z>-{0,1}\d+),"
    "(?<e2te>\d+),"
    "(?<s2le>\d+),"
    "(?<s2te>\d+),"
```

Is there a correct way to terminate/continue the line within a text block in PowerShell?

Bonus question:
Are comments allowed within the regex pattern string?
(e.g. Perl allows `(?# my comments)` or the `/x` modifier)

Comment: There cannot be _any_ leading whitespace, unless you want it, when using a here string. You have not shown us how you are terminating it either. I am not clear where your issue lies. Also depending on how your string is formatted regex might be a poor choice here.

Comment: `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnorePatternWhitespace`

Comment: @PetSerAl Just a fountain of useful tidbits you are

Comment: Added termination. Thank you.  and thank you for  letting me know the blocks are called here-strings.  Yes, IngorePatternWhitespace will work.  I guess I still have a general here-strings question:  is the length of each line only  dependent on the position of the non-visible terminator (cr or crlf) and are those non-visible characters now part of the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation is one way to achieve what you want:

```
$regexDatum = [regex](
  '^\<(?<TargetAddress>[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]),' +
  '(?<ReadStatus>\w\w),' +
  '(?<s1le>\d+),' +
  '(?<s1te>\d+),' +
  '(?<e1le>\d+),' +
  '(?<e1z>-{0,1}\d+),' +
  '(?<e1te>\d+),' +
  '(?<e2le>\d+),' +
  '(?<e2z>-{0,1}\d+),' +
  '(?<e2te>\d+),' +
  '(?<s2le>\d+),' +
  '(?<s2te>\d+),'
)
```

However, using the [`IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Whitespace) [regex option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630913/powershell-regex-textblock#comment60858111_36630913) suggested is arguably the better approach, because it allows indenting and commenting the expression within the string:

```
$regexDatum = @"
  ^\<(?<TargetAddress>[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]),
  (?<ReadStatus>\w\w),
  (?<s1le>\d+),
  (?<s1te>\d+),          # some comment
  (?<e1le>\d+),
  (?<e1z>-{0,1}\d+),     # other comment
  (?<e1te>\d+),
  (?<e2le>\d+),          # unimportant
  (?<e2z>-{0,1}\d+),
  (?<e2te>\d+),
  (?<s2le>\d+),
  (?<s2te>\d+),
"@

[regex]::Match($str, $regexDatum, [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```